# MongoDB call stats() from C++

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am probably missing something pretty obvious but for now cannot figure it out - how to query "db.collectionname.stats()" in MongoDB from the C++ driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the MongoDB runCommand version of that command, collStats:

```
{ collStats: "collection" , scale : 1024 }
```

which runs stats() on the collection "collection" displaying the results in kilobytes.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collStats/

To issue runCommands using the c++ driver you will want to use `DBClientWithCommands::runCommand()` :

http://api.mongodb.org/cxx/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_with_commands.html#a06c157017a74badc8831e2f66a34cc2a